# Calculate the limit of a sequence to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac{2n^3+3n^2-4n-5}{2^n+3^n}\right)$.

Any tips on where to start?

Note the solution is $0$.

Comment: You can use that an exponential grows faster than any polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to do so, just use the L'Hospital rule $3$ times to get rid of the polynomial and use that $2^n$ and $3^n \to+\infty$ in the limit when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would I write the denominator in terms of exponentials?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to derivate the denominator and the nominator 3 times, and then take the limit. In doing so, the nominator will turn into a constant and the denominator will be a sum of the form $a 2^n + b 3^n$.